# Convert python list into Unescaped-TSV

Tags: python, csv

I want to covert a python list into an Unescaped-TSV. I tried using

```
python list = [a, b, c]

a = "\t".join(str(x) for entry in python_list)
```

but it result in:

```
a b c
```

what I need:

```
a\tb\tc
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for python raw strings. Prefacing a string literal in python with an `r` will ignore escape codes such as `\t`.

Example:
In the REPL it will yield

```
>>>r"\t".join(["a","b","c"]) 
'a\\tb\\tc'
```

Writing this to a file will yield your intended results, with \t being escaped.

```
>>>with open("test.txt",'w') as f:
>>>    f.write("\\t".join(['a','b','c']))
```

The contents of test.txt will be `a\tb\tc`

You can find further documentation under String Literals of the python docs:

https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals